# AWS Cloud Watch unreadable symbols

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get all logs from docker (from stdout) on my EC2 instance. So after configuring policy and IAM roles, in my docker-compose.yml I add next configuration for logging:

```
django:
...
logging:
  driver: "awslogs"
  options:
    awslogs-region: "eu-central-1"
    awslogs-group: "my-group-auto"
    awslogs-stream: "my-stream"
    awslogs-create-group: "true"
```

Django config:

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': True,
  'root': {
     'level': 'ERROR',
     'handlers': ['console'],
  },
  'formatters': {
     'message-only': {
        'format': '%(message)s'
     }
  },
  'handlers': {
     'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'message-only'
     }
  },
  'loggers': {
     'celery': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
     }
  }
}
```

Then I run the python shell and try to send some logs:

```
In [1]: import logging
In [2]: logger = logging.getLogger('celery')
In [3]: logger.info('info2')
In [4]: logger.info('info22')
```

But on AWS Cloud Watch I got logs with unreadable symbols before original log message:

```
16:34:27    [J[?7h[0m[?12l[?25h[?2004linfo2
16:35:23    [J[?7h[0m[?12l[?25h[?2004linfo22
```

Looks like some unreadable date before the messages. How can I remove it?

Comment: Can you try python instead of ipython and see if the result is same? These are color encodings which are reaching your logs

Comment: Your solution works fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try python for this. IPython might be enhancing the logs with colors and the characters you see are color encodings.

Run your code in python and it should work.